# Show that the equation represents a sphere, find center and radius

Tags: calculus

$2x^2 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 = 8x - 24z + 1$

So here's my guess:

$2x^2 - 8x + 2y^2 + 2z^2 + 24z = 1$ 
     Get all variables on one side

$2x^2 - 8x + 16 + 2y^2 + 2z^2 + 24z + 144 = 1 + 16 + 144$ Complete square

$(2x - 8)^2 + 2y^2 + (2z^2 + 24)^2 = 161$ Stopped here

Is it possible to complete the square with the $y$ value too? Would it just be 1?

Comment: Take a step back and check your work. Even allowing for $(2z^2+24)^2$ being a typo (this generates a term in $z^4$), expanding the last equation produces nothing resembling the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it: divide through by $2$ to get
$$ x^2+y^2+z^2=4x-12z+\frac{1}{2}$$
$$ x^2-4x+y^2+z^2 +12 z=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Now, to complete the square for $x^2-4x$ we need to add $4$ to both sides. To complete the square for $z^2+12z$ we need to add $36$ to both sides. In total we add $40$ to both sides to get
$$ x^2-4x+4+y^2+z^2+12z+36=\frac{81}{2}$$
$$ (x-2)^2+y^2+(z+6)^2=\frac{81}{2}.$$
As we know, this is the equation  for a sphere of radius $9/\sqrt{2}$ centred at $(2,0,-6)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(2x)^2 \ne 2x^2$. The answer is:
$$2(x-2)^2 + 2(y-0)^2 + 2(z+6)^2 = 8 + 0 + 72 + 1$$
Thus, center $(2,0,-6)$, and radius $\sqrt{81/2}$.